# How can I cancel an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

In a method returning `IEnumerable<>`, I'm opening and looping over a resource (e.g. a database row reader). Once the loop finished, the resource is closed again.

However, it may happen that the caller decides not to finish the enumeration. This leaves the resource open.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> Bar ()
{
    using (var r = OpenResource()) {
        while (r.Read ()) {
            yield return r;
        }
    }
}

// OK - this closes the resource again
foreach (var foo in Bar()) {
    Console.WriteLine (foo);
}

// Not OK - resource stays open!
Console.WriteLine (Bar().First());
```

How would I solve this? Can I easily cancel an enumeration, i.e. tell it to skip over the rest of the loop, or dispose it (putting the cleanup code in `Dispose`)?

I considered returning a `Func<Result, bool>` so the user can have it return `false` if he's done with iterating. Similarly, some kind of cancel token could be used, too. But both approaches seem cumbersome to me.

Comment: I searched and found no similar question, though I'm sure there should be one - this is a pretty basic question imo.

Comment: `break;` should cancel it and the generated code should dispose of the enumerator. if the source doesn't do things properly, then that needs fixed.

Comment: @DanielA.White I want to cancel it at the caller scope, not inside the enumeration method itself

Comment: please post an example.

Comment: What about wrapping the method in a task and using task cancellation?

Comment: your second example should dispose of the enumerator.

Comment: Can you provide evidence of your claim that the resource is not disposed?  Show us code that clearly reproduces the problem.

Comment: @EricLippert I tried but was unable to create a working example. I misunderstood enumerables, and it seems `First()` does indeed dispose its argument. Sorry that I did not check this more properly before. I am confused though as I believe I had trouble with something similar before - but I can't remember what it was.

Comment: @EricLippert You should add that as an answer. If you have a link to more information on the behavior in question readily at hand, I would be glad for that, too.

Answer (score 14):

Normally it is the `IEnumerator<>` that implements the `IDisposable`, and if you look at the definition of `IEnumerator<>` you'll see that:

```
public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IDisposable, IEnumerator
```

The `foreach` statement correctly `Dispose()` the `IEnumerator<>` that receives from the `IEnumerable<>`, so that:

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> res = SomeQuery();

foreach (SomeClass sc in res)
{
    if (something)
        break;
}
```

upon exiting the `foreach` in any way (the `break`, an exception, naturally finishing `res`), the `Dispose()` of the `IEnumerator<>` should be called. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx for an example of how the `foreach` is implemented (a `try`... `finally`... with a `Dispose()` inside the `finally`)

Note that the C# will produce "correct" code for `using` used inside a `yield` function. See for example here: http://goo.gl/Igzmiz

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Bar()
{
    using (var r = OpenResource()) 
    {
        while (r.Read ()) 
        {
            yield return new Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

is converted to something that

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    int num = this.<>1__state;
    if (num == -3 || num == 1)
    {
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            this.<>m__Finally1();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Dispose()` method of `IEnumerator<>` will call a `m__Finally1` method that will `(IDisposable)this.<r>5__1.Dispose();` (where `5__1` is the `r` returned from `OpenResource()`). The `m__Finally` is even called if the code simply "exits" the `while (r.Read ())`:

```
if (!this.<r>5__1.Read())
{
    this.<>m__Finally1();
```

and/or if there is an exception.

```
 catch
 {
     this.System.IDisposable.Dispose();
```